# Who do I contact to get software updated in the Software Center?

Tags: software-center

For those who are still using blender on Ubuntu 11.04, the version in the Software Center is out of date (2.49). Yes, it does make a difference, there was a major user interface change with the release of Blender 2.5. For those using Blender in Ubuntu 11.10, the version in the Software Center is also out of date(2.57). The current release of Blender is 2.60. Who can I contact go get the versions in the two Software Centers updated? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this Ubuntu Documentation page on Ubuntu Backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports). In general, software that ships with a particular Ubuntu release will stay at that version except in the case of bug and security fixes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally Ubuntu releases the packages with a distro release and the only updates for them are bugs or security updates, if you want to use later versions of the software you probably need to add a PPA to your list.

[This PPA](https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/blender) supplies the latest 2.60 version for 11.10, to add it to your system use these commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:user/irie-blender
```

After that use these commands to update your package list and possible packages

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Package `blender` will install 2.60 in Ubuntu 11.04, 2.49.2 in Ubuntu 11.04. For 2.50 in 11.04 install package `blender2.5`.

Comment: What is the point of the software center if everything is out of date?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the answer you were hoping for, but I've started handling this manually myself.

I've started downloading the Linux tar.gz files from the Blender website and extracting them to /opt, and updating a symbolic link to the latest folder.

This way, all I have to do is point a launcher to /opt/blender/blender to launch the latest version.

Comment: Thank you for taking care of this. All I wanted to do was make sure that someone knew about this issue. I'm glad that you have taken it upon yourself.